# How to change UISwitch's text iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, custom-controls, uiswitch

i used the code (categorie) below to change the bu it didn't works.

the code : (original code taken from [iphone cookbook](http://code.google.com/p/cookbooksamples/downloads/list) chapter 8)

```
#import "UISwitch+Extended.h"

@interface UISwitch (extended)
- (void) setAlternateColors:(BOOL) boolean;
@end

@interface _UISwitchSlider : UISlider
@end

@implementation UISwitch (Extended)

- (_UISwitchSlider *) slider { 
    return [[self subviews] lastObject]; 
}
- (UIView *) textHolder { 
    return [[[self slider] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; 
}
- (UILabel *) leftLabel { 
    return [[[self textHolder] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; 
}
- (UILabel *) rightLabel { 
    return [[[self textHolder] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; 
}
- (void) setLeftLabelText: (NSString *) labelText { 
    [[self leftLabel] setText:labelText]; //error occurred here.
}
- (void) setRightLabelText: (NSString *) labelText { 
    [[self rightLabel] setText:labelText]; 
}
```

Any idea please.

Comment: A prime example of why relying on private view hierarchies is a terrible idea. This is a hack, and like most hacks it breaks as soon as anything changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code accesses subviews by indexes and they may have changed in new iOS. Print all subviews of the switch and find ones you need.

Comment: i did yes [[[self textHolder] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] returns UIImageview also there is no UILabel inside the UIView ([[self textHolder] subviews])

Comment: maybe it's somewhere deeper, maybe they now use images instead of text, you can display them somewhere to check this and change if you want. sorry, I don't have exact solution.